# Match 2 columns in different sheets and copy 3rd column from one sheet into another for matched cells

Tags: excel

I have the following data in 2 excel sheets in same file:

**Sheet 1:**

```
COLUM1
Field1
Field2
Field3
Field4
Field5
Field6
```

**Sheet2:**

```
COLUM1  COLUM2
Field1  Val1
Field2  Val2
Field3  Val2
Field4  Val3
Field5  Val2
Field6  Val5
```

What I want is an `excel` native method to match the values in COLUM1 of both sheets and add the corresponding COLUM2 value in a new column in Sheet 1. I looked for `IFMATCH` and `VLOOKUP` but couldn't figure out a way to copy the data as I am very inexperienced with excel.

Comment: Please share how you tried `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 0):

=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE)

But what if  !!!  the value in Sheet1 columnA doesn't correspond to any
values in the area sheet2 $A$1:$B$7???

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE)=TRUE),"",VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$7,2,FALSE))

Comment: See my answer for the use of the new XLOOKUP function. It handles "not found" so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Excel, use [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) instead of [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-942f678a-1bfc-4ccf-8dfa-f5057ded5c65). It is much easier to understand, read, and handles the "not found" case better.

=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found])

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$7,"Not found")
```

[image: Picture of inputs, formula, and results]